# How to output the result in the same line using loop in a list (list included string and variable) Python 3?

Tags: python

I have these 5 variables assigned to the sum of 5 different columns:

```
TotalUnitsSold = mmSalesDF['Units Sold'].sum()
TotalUnitsCost = mmSalesDF['Unit Cost'].sum()
TotalRevenue = mmSalesDF['Total Revenue'].sum()
TotalCost = mmSalesDF['Total Cost'].sum()
TotalProfit = mmSalesDF['Total Profit'].sum()
```

I need to write it to a new txt file using append, so I created a list[] with both string and variables:

```
sumsList = ['Sums:', 
            'Units sold:',TotalUnitsSold, 
            'Unit cost:',TotalUnitsCost, 
            'Total revenue:',TotalRevenue, 
            'Total cost:',TotalCost,
            'Total profit:',TotalProfit]
with open('DataSample/MM_Calc.txt', "a+") as writer:
    for line in sumsList:
        writer.write(f'{line}\n')
```

Here is the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2UpH.png)

But the required format should be like:
[Required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLPVa.png)

So I wonder is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Single values, single lines. You could format the data in the list: `f'Units sold: {TotalUnitsSold}',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TotalUnitsSold = 5
    TotalUnitsCost = 600
    TotalRevenue = 60
    TotalCost = 5000
    TotalProfit = 100

    sumsList = ['Sums:',
                'Units sold: ' + str(TotalUnitsSold),
                'Unit cost: ' + str(TotalUnitsCost),
                'Total revenue: ' + str(TotalRevenue),
                'Total cost: ' + str(TotalCost),
                'Total profit: ' + str(TotalProfit)]
    with open('MM_Calc.txt', "w+") as writer:
        for line in sumsList:
            writer.write(f'{line}\n')

    #output:
    Sums:
    Units sold: 5
    Unit cost: 600
    Total revenue: 60
    Total cost: 5000
    Total profit: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your list this way:

```
sumsList = ['Sums:', 
            'Units sold: ({})'.format(TotalUnitsSold), 
            'Unit cost: ({})'.format(TotalUnitsCost), 
            'Total revenue: ({})'.format(TotalRevenue), 
            'Total cost: ({})'.format(TotalCost),
            'Total profit: ({})'.format(TotalProfit)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sumsList = ['Sums:', 
            'Units sold:',TotalUnitsSold, 
            'Unit cost:',TotalUnitsCost, 
            'Total revenue:',TotalRevenue, 
            'Total cost:',TotalCost,
            'Total profit:',TotalProfit]
```

You put all of them to list as item, not lines.

```
for line in sumsList:
```

When you loop it like this, it will print a newline after each one.

Try like this if you want to use list only and print like key-value in same line.

```
sumsList = ['Sums:', 
            'Units sold: ' + str(TotalUnitsSold), 
            'Unit cost: ' + str(TotalUnitsCost), 
            'Total revenue: ' + str(TotalRevenue), 
            'Total cost: ' + str(TotalCost),
            'Total profit: ' + str(TotalProfit)]
```